# No exact matches in call to initializer when initializing Data in AppStorage

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

I'm learning how to store custom types in `AppStorage`, and came across an issue. In this simplified example, I'm trying to save an empty `Int` array to AppStorage once the view is created.

The following code gives me the error, `No exact matches in call to initializer` . I know that this error usually means there are mismatching types somewhere, but I'm not sure what the types *should* be, or how to fix it.

```
struct test: View {
    
    init() {
        let emptyList = [Int]()
        guard let encodedList = try? JSONEncoder().encode(emptyList) else { return }
        self.storedList = encodedList
    }
    
    @AppStorage("stored_list") var storedList: Data      //NO EXACT MATCHES TO CALL IN INITIALIZER
    
    //"body" implementation not shown
}
```

Why is this error occurring, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you doing with all the variables in the init? Make sure you post real code. And what is player_list?

Comment: Name of key for AppStorage should be a String, and this wrapper should be used somewhere in View, not in model.

Comment: JoakimDanielson, sorry for the poorly made example! I edited it to make it simpler. Also @Asperi, this is all of the code from the example I used to reproduce it. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be either with default value or optional, so correct variants are

```
@AppStorage("stored_list") var storedList: Data = Data()
```

or

```
@AppStorage("stored_list") var storedList: Data?
```